# .NET 3.5 SP1 and ADo.NET Entity Framework

Tags: .net, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have .NET 3.5 SP1 installed on my machine and VS 2008.
I wanted to work with the ADO.NET Entity Data Model, but when clicking on ADD-> New Item and under data tab I am not able to see the option for Entity data model..Why is it so? 
Didnt the Ado.NEt Entity framework come with the .net 3.5 sp1?

Answer (score 3):

After you select `Add --> New Item`,  click on the ***`Data`*** in `categories` here you will see ***`ADO.NET Entity Data Model`***. You may have missed it due to the item starting with ***`ADO.NET`***

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that your project's target framework is lower than 3.5. Check properties.